# How to close a part when error occurs during initialization in eclipse e4 rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have to load some data in the `@PostConstruct` method of my Part. It is possible that this data is not available in some cases. In this case, I would like to gracefully close the Part and show the user a message in a dialog.

What I do is that I catch the "no data found" exception and use `MessageDialog.openError()` method to show the user that the Part cannot be initialized. After this I would like to close/hide this Part. I am using 
`partService.hidePart(part, true)` to accomplish this but the framework throws an exception:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:348)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.setData(Widget.java:1228)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.bindWidget(SWTPartRenderer.java:125)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:985)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:766)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:737)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:715)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1246)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:69)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:488)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:454)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:705)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:682)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:620)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:608)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1137)
at com.example.handler.OpenProjectEditorHandler.execute(OpenProjectEditorHandler.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:196)
at com.example.ui.controller.NavigatorController.openEditor(NavigatorController.java:169)
at com.example.ui.MyPart.lambda$0(NavigatorPart.java:54)
at com.example.ui.NavigatorPart$$Lambda$1/870593736.doubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:831)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:828)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1472)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1237)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:164)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: If there is no data, I recommend to nevertheless open the view and show a label or similar that indicates that there is no data - and if applicable a hint where to enter data or a refresh button. This would be much more _in line_ with how other Eclipse plug-ins behave.

Comment: Even though the answer from @greg-449 is the relevant answer to my question. I did end up following the approach mentioned by Rüdiger Herrmann because it seemed to be more user friendly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the part in the `@PostConstruct` method is probably confusing Eclipse.

Try using `UISynchronize.asyncExec` to run the code after the `@PostConstruct` has finished running. Something like:

```java
@Inject
private UISynchronize uiSynch;

...

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct()
{
  .... other code

  uiSynch.asyncExec(() ->
     {
        ... hide the part
     });
}
```